# Only showing unanswered questions!

Tags: support

A day ago I went (for the first time) to the task "UNANSWERED". After that, whenever I go to the "ALL QUESTIONS", when I go to the second page (and more), is ONLY shown unanswered questions! That is very strange! ¿Why?

Comment: I'm not exactly certain where you are in math.SE's tabs. My almost think that your "QUESTIONS" tab is set to the "unanswered" subtab. In this case, just switch over to a different subtab (like "newest").  If this is not the case, could you post a screenshot (or somehow indicate exactly where you are in the tabs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via cookies, the site tries to remember your preferences.

If you visited the "unanswered" tab, the "unanswered" tab will become your default preferred tab. To switch to a different tab (for example "active"), click on the preferred tab and it should be remembered from now on.

The same is true for the sorting of answers. You have three choices, "active", "oldest", and "votes". Selecting one out of the three will mark that as your preferred viewing method, until the next time you make a selection and chooses a different sorting method.